# Visual Studio String Visualizer with WSL2

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022, wsl-2

Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.1.0 and Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2

My project is a CMake project imported with Open->Folder into VS.

With other Windows projects, when I debug in VS I can use the String Visualizer to view it as Text, XML, HTML or JSON, but when I choose the WSL2 as the build target and debug, I don't see the option to use String Visualizer at all.

String Visualizer options are showing when I debug Windows program:
[image: String Visualizer with Windows application]

No String Visualizer option when I debug in WSL2:
[image: No String Visualizer option when I debug in WSL2]

Any way to enable String Visualizer for WSL2?